Bamboo - How to use branch overrides?
I am currently working on a Bamboo project.
I have a unique branch with the configuration inside (using Bamboo specs - just one branch with all the files) .
Now , I would like to use this branch to run my plans but override some jobs for certain branches : my idea was to use the "branch-overrides" for these branches, but the override is ignored.
How can I do this?
I've tried to use the branch-overrides tags in the YAML document , I would expect to override the configuration of some branches

Stackoverflow has those questions from about 2017. I know that back than it wasn't possible, but in more recent Bamboo versions it was enabled. It's even mentioned here - https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/8.2.1/specs.html?yaml#overriding-branch-settings-using-bamboo-specs
I'm trying to achieve the same thing now. So far without success, will update if something works

As mentioned in the Enhanced plan branch configuration, you can have different content inside the "bamboo-specs" folder of each branch.
Does your setup follows all the listed prerequisites?


You are using Bamboo Specs to configure plan branches.
Your code and Bamboo Specs are stored in the same Bitbucket Data Center or Bitbucket Cloud and at the same level as the bamboo-specs folder. See Integrating Bamboo with Bitbucket Data Center and Integrating Bamboo with Bitbucket Cloud, and Integrating Bamboo with GitHub.
Your repository is configured as a linked repository of the Bitbucket type
Plan branch detection is enabled (it’s on by default). See Using plan branches.


It is important to have the bamboo specs configured on your "main" branch first (it might be main, master - the one that is marked as DEFAULT BRANCH in Bitbucket).
After you configure your main branch correctly, you could set on it the rules for branch-overrides or, if needed, to have completely different bamboo-specs on your other branches.
